# Redirecting query based on Sql (Inserting values into Dual)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, crystal-reports

My Idea is to insert multiple rows into dual table.

I have a query in which my requirement is when I enter % as my parameter it should got to 1 query else it should go to another query . It is showing a error at  (&a1='%')

When I execute this query it asks for prompt and I will enter % and it should got to the query "select module_package, module_name from ops$glimsne.tim_modules"

My code is as follows

```
DECLARE 

   ab tim_modules_tbl%rowtype;
   a11 tim_modules_tbl%rowtype;

begin
 (
 select a1, b1 into ab,a11 from (
 case 
 when &a1='%' Then
  (select module_package, module_name from ops$glimsne.tim_modules)
    else
(select module_id, module_name from ops$glimsne.tim_modules)

    end
  )dual );
END;
```

It should display all values in Dual table

Comment: I'm not sure you can use a case statement in the from clause like that.

Comment: you could corrupt your database by inserting records into dual (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388).

Comment: Then How do I do this I need to switch queries based on parameter that i have selected

Comment: I do not have a crystal reports background. I would research using  SQL Expression Fields.